# Cannot read file via docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a spring-boot application and I have some files placed inside /src/main/java/resources which I am trying to read it in my code.  When the same code tries to read from docker container it says file does not exist. The same code works perfectly fine via localhost

The files are under /src/main/java/resources/data folder and this is my code which tries to read the file

```
 private String getJson(String folderName, String id, StringBuilder sb) throws Exception {
        String responseJson = null;
        String filePath = "data" + File.separator + folderName + File.separator + id + ".json";
        LOG.info("printing filePath : " + filePath);
        LOG.info("printing id : " + id);
        File f = new File(filePath);
       // if(f.exists()){
            try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
                LOG.info("printing inputStream : " + inputStream);
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    responseJson = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                }
                if (responseJson == null || responseJson.isEmpty()) {
                    LOG.info("json response is null : ");
                    throw new JsonNotFoundException(Constant.JSON_NOT_FOUND);
                }
                sb.append(responseJson);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.info("IO exception : ");
                throw new IOException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info(" exception : ");
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
//        }
//        else{
//            LOG.info("file doesnt exists : " + filePath);
//        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

An example for the file path : src/main/resources/data/get-products/1420-17612-82.json
Docker file content

```
{
  "commands":
  [
    "rm -rf .tmp",
    "git clone git@github.com:{orgnname}/{test-service.git} -b COECP-973-Configure-logging-mechanism-for-Service .tmp/test-service",
    "docker build .tmp/test-service/.docker/build/db -t local/test-service/db",
    "docker build .tmp/test-service -t local/test-service/app"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you compile and run the application? Does the container even have access to `src`? Even without Docker, usually Java applications get compiled into jar files, do not have their source code present after they are deployed and you have to load resources from the classloader, not from the file system.

Comment: Ok. They are in my class path after compilation under /classes/data and I am trying to load them via classloader

Comment: So I edited my question and attached the full source code

Comment: Sry /src/main/resources is correct path. Also, add dockerfile content in the question.

Comment: yes it is  /src/main/java/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... you messed path for `File` and for resources from class path. What is the reason to have `File f = new File(filePath);`?

Here are things:

1. If you use `File` - files must be available to the JVM and as long as you use relative path like `data\folderxxx\filexxx.json` it must be available in container file system. I.e. `data` folder must be placed in image or mounted from outside exactly into directory from where JVM runs
2. If you use `ClassLoader` and `ResourceAsStream` root of your `data` directory must be defined in class path for JVM or be in Jar file - it is a root in classpath as well. Check your jar file - if `data` directory is in root of jar - all fine and files will be available by `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)`, *but not for `new File(filePath)`!*

if not - make it happen or update your filePath for `ResourceAsStream` accordingly.

Comment: Yes that was messed up with new File(). I just removed it and it just worked

Answer (score 2):

I have had faced the same issue earlier, though our requirement got more complex over time, but the following code should solve your problem:

```
    ClassPathResource cp = new ClassPathResource("relative_path_to_file");
    File f = null;

    if (cp.exists())
        f = cp.getFile();
```

Comment: This one worked, I was using ItextPdf library and it expects the absolute path(not the actual file). so did cp.getFile().getAbsolutePath().

Comment: is this `ClassPathResource` a special library class?